# Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: ConnectApi.BinaryInput

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-chatter

i write a code in apex for setting the chatter photo of a user . i write a function

```apex
public PageReference setPhoto() {
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    string firstImageURL = 'https://ap1.salesforce.com/resource/1377118388000/sample_pic';
    firstImageURL = firstImageURL.replace(' ', '%20');
    req.setEndpoint(firstImageURL);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    req.setCompressed(true);
    req.setTimeout(60000);
    HttpResponse res = null;
    res = h.send(req);
    blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
    ConnectApi.BinaryInput bb = ConnectApi.BinaryInput(image, 'image/png', 'myfile');
    System.debug('user is' + ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.setPhoto(null, '00590000001jFln', bb));
    return null;
}
```

when i try to save it it is giving me error

```
Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: ConnectApi.BinaryInput(Blob, String, String) at line 28 column 27
```

and i am following this http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectAPI_inputs.htm#capi_binary_input 
can you please guideline whether this documentation is wrong or right ?? and how to get ConnectApi.BinaryInput instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'are trying to use the instance method as a static. Create an instance of `ConnectApi.BinaryInput`

```apex
ConnectApi.BinaryInput binaryInput = new ConnectApi.BinaryInput(fileBlob, null, filename);
```